# Generating random position for electron within 3D orbitals

Tags: electrons, atomic-physics, orbitals

Apologies in advance if this is the wrong StackExchange to ask this question in... if it is not, please don't just down-vote, let me know where else to go and I will gladly. I'm just trying to learn. I'm trying to build a [3D representation of an Atoms (and Molecules)](https://darrylhuffman.com/atom/) with *accurate* electron placement. (AKA not the Bohr's Model, instead, [electron orbitals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atomic_orbital#Orbitals_table)) So, is there any formula I can use in order to generate a random 3D point within any of the different electron orbitals? Or, more possibly, is there a formula I can use to create 3D models of all the electron orbital configurations? Or maybe there are already 3D models of this created that I can use in my own project?

If I can manage to generate or get a 3D model of these orbital configurations, I think I can just pick a random point within the orbitals corresponding to an element in order to place the electrons in a somewhat accurate fashion.

I appreciate any help, and send thanks in advance for any insight you may have!

Comment: The answer to your question is (at least superficially) obvious to me which is why I initially downvoted: Find the position wavefunctions of electrons in an atom. However, I found that googling for such wavefunctions isn't as easy as I assumed it would be.

Comment: For anything beyond hydrogen, I suspect it will be quite difficult to find simple equations to give you the shapes of your oribitals (and to utilize those, you will need clouds rather than spheres for the electrons). I wouldn't be surprised if orbitals for heavier atoms aren't even described by analytically solvable solutions. And if you want to do organic, molecules, it should get even fancier with hybridization.

Comment: Furthermore, I think "is there any formula I can use in order to generate a random 3D point within any of the different electron orbitals?" won't exactly work because you can't exactly say that 'the electron jumps to a different random point every instant, and I will put a white sphere in each of those positions":

Comment: What I plan on doing is taking "screenshot" of the atom and it's electrons and displaying them as a still capture. Perhaps every few seconds I'd "update" the screenshot to make it apparent that the electrons location is always based on probability.

Comment: But the screenshot would still show the electron as a point whose position changes randomly, right? Because that's not exactly what is happening, and I can imagine that it would look really strange to show a randomly flashing white dot; the shapes of different orbitals will be far from apparent.

Comment: Would a DFT solution be acceptable? That does mean running the DFT for each situation of interest and validating it though...

Comment: Have a look at DFT softwares. Some are open source. With this, you can calculate the electronic density of atoms, molecules and full bodies.

Answer (score 1):

"Accurate electron placement". As far as I know, electrons are just probability clouds so placing them accurately is not possible. Your best bet would be to use Bohr's model if you want to place them.

What you can also do is to show them as [orbitals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atomic_orbital). These are essentially probability clouds where you can find the electron most of the time. This would be a more accurate model.

By the way, your website is beautiful.

Comment: By accurate electron placement, I mean that I would like to place them randomly within their corresponding orbital probability cloud. However, in order to do that, I need to either be able to generate or receive the 3D model for all the different orbital cloud configurations. Thanks by the way! I've put a lot of effort into it and am trying to expand it further. :)

Comment: The s-orbital is very easy. It's just a sphere which you can generate easily.

Comment: Can't you manually write the expressions using [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atomic_orbital#Orbitals_table) as reference.

Comment: "Your best bet would be to use Bohr's model if you want to place them." that's probably the most important bit in this answer. Atomic orbitals just don't logically give you a new random point for each instant.

Comment: @Chair I think he he is talking about randomly generating the electron within the orbital every second.

Comment: @harshit54 you're correct, as I just commented on my main post, "What I plan on doing is taking "screenshot" of the atom and it's electrons and displaying them as a still capture. Perhaps every few seconds I'd "update" the screenshot to make it apparent that the electrons location is always based on probability." I suppose I can probably try and manually write the expressions using that wikipedia table as a reference but I wanted it to be accurate so I thought it might be good to ask.

Comment: @harshit54 Yeah, but that doesn't make sense... you measure the electron once, and then it'll be in a certain place. If you measure it the next second, and then the second after that, and then a hundered times again, you won't get something like the wavefunction. You only see such a distribution if you measure a hundered _independent and identical_ systems. It doesn't make sense to assign one exact random place for one second and a different random coordinate point for the next second, because that's not what's actually happening.

Comment: @Chair Obviously that's not what's actually happening. He cannot be 100% accurate. But it can suffice if he just wants to build a website with models of atom.

Comment: Also one thing you can do to be more accurate is to sometimes(1 in 20 times) to generate the electron outside the orbital.

Comment: I dunno, I think it would be better to just use a conventional bohr model, rather than ending up with a misleading representation of orbitals. Though the bohr model isn't right, it has a good deal of explanatory power, and it's something standard which shows up in a good deal of resources. A representation of orbitals which uses flickering points rather than clouds would be confusing since I'm quite sure that there aren't many resources which use that image and it has some downright incorrect implications (e.g. it almost says that repeated measurements give random outcomes)

Comment: @Chair Quick off-topic question here, are you still in high school?

Comment: @harshit54 you're better off asking such questions in the h bar (I think you've popped in before; I'm usually pingable), but yes, my 12th grade finals are in may.

Comment: @Chair Can we [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/90588/discussion-between-harshit54-and-chair)?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest the use of a DFT package such as [QUANTUM ESPRESSO](http://www.quantum-espresso.org/) or other similar open source or free softwares. I think there are tutorials to be found easily on the Internet. With this, you can calculate the electronic density of atoms, molecules and even complex solids.

Then, as you say, once you have the electronic density, it is easy to pick a random point from the given density.